# How do I add 'select all', and 'other' options in Bootstrap form

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap to create an email sign-up form.

I've been asked to create a select option for products interested in.

```
<label>Products interested in:</label>

<select>
<option>Select all</option>
<option>Product A</option>
<option>Product B</option>
<option>Other</option>
</select>
```

As you can see there two option there that don't work out of the box.

A) Select all
B) Other

Can anyone tell me how to implement these options?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want the 2 options to do? For any product or "select all and Other" you will need an event after that option has been selected.

I'm guessing you will need to use jquery to do something with the selection otherwise it will just "sit" in the select box.